# How to see what command-line options handbrake sends to mencoder

Tags: video, conversion, video-conversion, mencoder, handbrake

I want to see what command-line options handbrake is sending to mencoder. I looked at the Activity Window and it shows a lot of stuff but not what I'm looking for. How can I find it?

Comment: at least under windows handbrake is not using mencoder. it uses libs from ffmpeg and other projects, but not the mencoder binary as far as i can see it. it uses HandBrakeCLI.exe

Comment: Seconded. What convinced you Handbrake uses mencoder in the first place? Also, what operating system are we talking about here?

Comment: Using OSX. Someone said that Handbrake was a frontend to mencoder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on my experience with Handbrake on Windows and Linux: it does *not* use mencoder. Instead it offers its own command line interface: [HandBrakeCLI](http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide).

On Windows one can click `Show Queue`>`Queue`>`Generate Batch Script` to export a script which contains all the command line parameters passed on to HandBrakeCLI. Although your reference to the "Activity Window" leads me to believe you're using Mac OS X, such an option may exist on the Mac version as well.

[image: Main window]
[image]

Comment: Appears to be outdated.  The only option within Show Queue for me is Start Queue in 1.0.7

Comment: Yup. Handbrake 1.0.7 doesn't even have the HandBrakeCLI anymore... :/

Answer (score 3):

The reason I found this thread here is because, on

https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide
I noticed :

... under "Video Options"

```
-x, --encopts <string>  Specify advanced encoding options in the same
                        style as mencoder (all encoders except theora):
                        option1=value1:option2=value2
```

AND :

under "Picture Settings"

```
--crop: controls the cropping values. The cropping has to be in the form Top:Bottom:Left:Right, so to crop 60pixels from the top, 58 from the bottom, 2 from the left, and 6 from the right, use --crop 60:58:2:6 

... do note that this is different from cropping in some other programs,
like MEncoder. If you don't enter this setting, HandBrake will
automatically detect how many pixels to crop to remove black borders.
```